# Creating Date and Time displays in MacOS App

Tags: swift, datetime, user-interface, interface-builder

I am trying to set up a date field and a time field within my MacOS app but am having trouble doing this on Swift. I am relatively new to Swift and I am not using storyboards. I have created a date formatting function to get the current date but it doesn't update my textField that I want it updating (*dateDisplay*).

Would I be able to get some guidance with this? I also wanted to know how to get a real time digital clock in here somehow and keep it independent from the date field, but am not sure how to do the time side of it. Anything I find online is for date and time fields is for iOS or uses storyboards and I am not working with either of these. Attached below is my date function. I don't know how to do the time function, and this date function isn't updating my *dateDisplay* TextField. It is fair to say that I am stuck.

```
func currentDate() {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    let str = formatter.string(from: Date())
    dateDisplay.stringValue = String(str)
    print(str)
}
```

Comment: "I am not using storyboards."  If you end your sentence like that, it will only make readers wonder how you put IBOutlet and IBAction objects together?  "Anything I find online is for date and time fields is for iOS"  What difference does that make?  "am not sure how to do the time side of it."  That's too broad.  See what you can do with DateFormatter's dateFormat property.  That's just one approach.

Comment: Do you use XIBs? When and from where do you call `currentDate()`? Do you know how to debug? Did you try something like `dateDisplay.stringValue = "Hello"` or `formatter.timeStyle = .short`?

Comment: Yes I am using the XIB files, so I can still create IBOutlets and IBActions. I am calling it from the IBAction I created that is linked to the textfield. Yeah I tried those before posting here but they weren't giving my any different results.